# Driving a 6V relay from an 3.3v GIO pin of Raspberry PI3

Tags: relay, raspberry-pi, driver

I want to drive [this 6v relay](https://www.conrad.be/ce/nl/product/508098/TE-Connectivity-RT314F06-Printrelais-6-VDC-16-A-1x-wisselaar-1-stuks) (RT314F06) from a 3.3v output gate of an GIO pin of a R-PI3.

--edit--

There is already [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/59603/how-can-i-drive-a-5v-120vac-80ma-with-15a-contacts-with-a-raspberry-pi) answer on SO, but it is incomplete in the way that it does not tell which discrete components to use. I my case this is important since I'm too novice to decide which components to choose myself.

--edit--

Given that I have also a 6v power-supply, what component should I use to upshift the 3.3v to 6v?

The relay requires 6V and has an internal resistance of 55 Ohm. So, if I am correct, the driver needs to be capable of driving about 100mA.

Can I use a converter like [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12009)? I think it can shift only to 6v and I can't find how much current it can drive.

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Please edit your question to show us how you calculated the 10 mA current.

Comment: O... indeed, 6/55*1000 = 100mA, right?

Comment: Why does your title say Arduino, but the text says Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The item you linked in your question is a logic level converter and so this would probably be unsuitable as it wouldn't be designed to work with currents around 100 mA.

The simplest implementation I can think of is this: -

[image]

It shows a 5 volt supply and relay but this will work with a 6 volt supply and relay. D1 is there to "catch" back emfs from the relay coil when you turn it off (MCU out = 0).

Choosing the base resistor at 1 kohm ensures that the transistor properly turns on when the collector load is only 49.5 ohms (55 ohm - 10%). The 2N2222 has a current gain guaranteed to be 100 at a collector current of 150 mA hence, with about 2.5 mA flowing into the base, the collector *could* deliver 260 mA should the load be much lower resistance. In this configuration I would expect the transistor to fully turn on to less than 0.5 volts and properly operate the relay.

Short story: You need to drive the BJT's base with enough current and choose a transistor that is rated for a decent hFE at currents in excess of 100 mA.

Comment: Actually this is better than my solution (because it uses fewer components). Don't quite understand why I didn't think of this myself :) As a remark, note that this inverts the GPIO output. The relay is on when the GPIO is low. In this case Q1 must be able to support 110mA of collector current.

Comment: @sigvaldm because I have many, many more years of work experience LOL! Inverting the GPIO is a strange thing to say. When GPIO is high, the relay is activated.

Comment: Yes, my bad. The relay is on when the GPIO is high.

Comment: I still like the solution of @sigvaldm since it has no signal on the lines when the relay does not have to be switched. The relay will be connected with a 10m signal cable.

Comment: @mvermand I think you are possibly confused. On my circuit, with GPIO = 0 the relay is inactive and with GPIO = 1, the relay is activated. I'm unsure if you have interpreted this as I do.

Comment: @Andyaka I mean: if I understand correctly your solution has two wires to the remote relay: one 5V line and one signal line. sigvaldm's solution has one 0V line and one signal line. That is what I meant... i prefer not to have tension on the lines unless needed. But I'm not an electronical expert (obviously), so I might be wrong or worrying about nothing.

Comment: @mvermand - that could be a problem but it all depends on the bigger picture. You could argue that when the relay is being driven 6 volts and 0 volts are roughly present on both circuits. Is this a problem? If the relay is active for about 50% of the time then statistically there isn't much of a case to answer. You have the bigger picture not I!

Comment: @Andyaka you are right about the picture, but the relay is a bi-stable relay, so switching on or off will require current but for a very limited amount of time. The time driving current will be minimal in my use-case: home-automation: switching light circuits... :-)

Comment: @Andyaka, I saw the edits to your answer. Are the mentioned components (1K resistor, 2N2222 transistor) in the schema still valid after these edits? I'm not really capable of translating your new remarks into changes to the components. Thanks a lot for your extensive answer!

Comment: @mvermand my added comments are about the circuit in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

In principle this SparkFun device changes the logic level from 3.3V to 5V/6V (your relay only needs >4.2V). However, I have doubts that this device will deliver enough current. From what I can see on the schematic your relay will be in series with a 10k resistor. 5V/10k=0.5mA is too small a current for your relay's primary coil (10mA). Perhaps the simplest circuit I can think of that does what you want is this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjmouF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
 where the NPN transistor is just any (powerful enough) NPN transistor. However, this is not a good solution and I'll explain why. I just included it for educational purposes, so you can see the mental steps I take to design circuitry. First, note that when the GPIO is off, R1 pulls the relay pin high (to 6V). Thus you have an inversion here, when the GPIO is high, the relay is off, and vice versa. But that's no problem. However, at this moment, R1 must be small enough to get at least 4.2V across the relay, that is at most:

$$
\frac{R_R}{R_R+R_1}=\frac{6V}{4.2V} \Rightarrow R_1=23.5\Omega
$$

And you will not get the full 6V across the relay. Moreover, when the GPIO is high, the transistor will pull the relay node to ground. At this moment the current through the transistor will be 6V/20Ohm = 0.3A so the transistor must handle 0.3A collector current, and R1 must be able to dissipate (6V)^2/20Ohm = 1.8W. Not only is this wasteful, it's also not a that common, most resistors being around hundreds of milliwatts. The value of R2 is not important, but it is necessary to avoid short-circuiting the BE-junction of the NPN. You could also use an N-MOS transistor in which case you don't need R2 (but it won't hurt).

Now let's look at the design I recommend you:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMfWDA.png)</sup>

Like before, Q2 inverts the GPIO but instead of driving the relay directly it drives another transistor Q1 (a PNP transistor). So now R1 can be quite standard. Since Q1 also inverts the signal the relay is on when the GPIO is on. Also note that I inserted a diode in parallel with the relay. This is common practice on inductive loads (such as the coil of a relay) since coils may spike with a negative voltage when turned off. In this case, the relay will alow this current to flow back and dissipate, and offer some protection of the transistor. The NPN transistor Q2 can be any standard transistor. Q1 must be able to deliver enough current for the relay, which is 6V/55Ohm = 110mA. Most cheap transistors can deliver about 200mA so this should not be a problem. Though I do not recommend going for a transistor with less than 200mA.

Comment: Thank you for this great explanation. Are the mentioned transistors (2N3904 & 2N3906) usable for this circuit?

Comment: Yes, the 2N3906 is capable of 200mA according to its datasheet, so that should be sufficient. But most PNP transistors will do, so if it's easier to get hold of another one, just check that it supports at least 200mA of collector current.

Comment: As a final disclaimer, although I'm confident with the design i provide you with (I have a master's degree in electrical engineering and a couple of years of work experience), I cannot be held liable for its use. Designing circuitry often takes trial and error.

Comment: I will not hold you liable. I am really great full for your explanation.